# NET Framework Version compatibility for Visual Studio Package

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, .net-framework-version

I have a visual studio package which currently targets .NET Framework version 4.5 and works with Visual Studio versions from 2012 up to 2019.

If I upgrade to .NET Framework 4.7.2, what does this mean for compatibility with different versions of Visual Studio?

Will it automatically make the package incompatible with older versions of Visual Studio (e.g. 2012, 2013 and 2015)?

Comment: No, probably not.  Unless that programmer does not allow Windows Update to keep his framework version updated, that isn't exactly the kind of customer you want.  Why target a maintenance release though?  4.7.2 doesn't add anything that's critical to an extension.  You'd only ever do that because you depend on a bug fix.

Comment: In this case it would be because I referenced a NuGet package which used 4.7.2.

Comment: Well, that would be another reason :)  Look for an earlier release.

Comment: I try to create an sample to test it, but was stuck that VS2012 can't load the VS shell 15.0. However, if you've known the approach that make an extension created from higher vs version to work in earlier vs version, I think one easy way to test the compatibility is to write an simple extension from VS2017 or VS2019 with .net4.7.2, and let it add ref to .net 4.7.2 reference and check if it works in VS2012.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. It sounds as if there should be no problem - providing the required framework is installed on the target machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you install a specific version of .net framework you can see that in your target framework.
you can use this address to see all the .net SDK for visual studio

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks?utm_source=getdotnetsdk&utm_medium=referral
you must attention, if you want to using .NetCore in your project you must have a newer version of Visual Studio like 2017 or 2019.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Maybe the question was not clear. I am the author of a Visual Studio Package which runs as an extension to Visual Studio. If I make a Visual Studio Extension using .NET Framework 4.7.2, will it still be possible to use this extension in - for example - Visual Studio 2013, which is itself older than Framework Version 4.7.2?

Comment: Yes it's possible to use that, but the user must have .net framework version where you wrote your code with that version.if they don't have that version appeal compilation error when they want to use from your extension.

Answer (score 0):

### An answer for those who doesn't need compatibility deeper than 2017

(But still ended up here from a search engine.)

Check system requirements.

For example, [Visual Studio 2017 Product Family System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2017/vs2017-system-requirements-vs) says that:

> Visual Studio requires .NET Framework 4.7.2 to run, and this will be
> installed during setup.

This means that we can be 100% sure that it's safe to target 4.7.2 when targeting VS 2017.

P.S.: The reason I limit backward compatibility to 2017 is I don't see any mentions of .NET framework in the system requirements of older versions, so this method won't help with targeting older versions.